# Any way to assign reactive store value to reactive state?

Tags: vue.js, state, vuejs3, store, vue-reactivity

I have a reactive store `store.js`:

```
import {reactive} from "vue";

const re = reactive({})

export default {
    re
}
```

which I'm using inside a component to assign a text value:

```
store.re.blog = 'Hello World!'
```

How can I assign this value to `state` inside another component? I've tried:

```
const state = reactive({
    content1: store.re.blog || '',
    content2: store.re.blog ? store.re.blog : ''
})
```

both of which don't work. I want to put the value in `state` because in the next step I'm sending the `state` object via `ajax` request to the database.

I'm using `vue 3` with `script setup`

Comment: If my answer satisfies you, please accept it and upvote it :) if no explain more please

Answer (score -1):

It works for me:

[image]

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <HelloWorld />
  <OtherComponentReceivingStoreValue />
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';
import OtherComponentReceivingStoreValue from "@/components/OtherComponentReceivingStoreValue.vue";

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    OtherComponentReceivingStoreValue,
    HelloWorld
  }
});
</script>
```

HelloWorld.vue:

```
<template>
  Component that initialize the store blog value
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import store from '@/store'

store.re.blog = 'Hello World!'
</script>
```

ComponentReadingTheStore:

```
<template>
  <div>
    store value:
    {{ state }}
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import store from '@/store'
import {reactive} from "vue";

const state = reactive({
  content1: store.re.blog || '',
  content2: store.re.blog ? store.re.blog : ''
})
</script>
```

If what you want is to change the store in the receiver component when the first component mutate the store, you have to put a watch or make a computed.